# how can i find the type names in the rally rest client for ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, rest, rally

under the 'read-me' section here:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby

it says:

```
#type names are stored in rally.rally_objects hash, you can inspect there for a list
```

i'm embarrassed to say i'm not really sure what that means.

in the given code sample there is a line like:

```
@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
```

and I inspected:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby/blob/master/lib/rally_api/rally_rest_json.rb

but didn't see any hash field called rally_objects, so i'm at a loss.

can someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up removing that variable in the most recent versions of rally_api- we'll make sure to update documentation.

When you are logged into Rally, you can look at the Help > upper right > Web Services API.  There is an area there to see all of the object types listed on the left and to test queries as needed in the main window on each artifact.

From rally_api, you can query on the "typedefinition" artifact and fetch Name, each type definition there is the name of an object you can work with.

Hope that helps.